# Are there any civil programs that uses S1000D?

Tags: commercial-aviation, publications

For civil programs, aircraft documentation (especially maintenance) used to follow ATA 100 or ATA iSpec 2200.

S1000D, on the other hand, is mostly used in military programs, but civil program may use this specification and clearly should supersede ATA-like documentation.

I found [this document](http://s1000d.org/downloads/documents/2012_uf/civil%20panel%20s1000d%20user%20forum%20denver%20cawg.pdf) that talks about S1000D implementation in civil aviation, but it is quite old.

For now, do you know of any civil program (in production or currently in development) that effectively uses S1000D? Which version do they use?

To my knowledge, the only civil programs currently writing documentation in S1000D are Airbus A350 and Boeing 787. Are there any other ones?

Comment: According to https://www.aecinc.com/company/blog/2015/09/18/considering-s1000d-for-your-aircraft-technical-documentation, Bombardier C-Series uses S1000D as well